# From yyyy-MM-dd to Timestamp

Tags: java, simpledateformat

I need to parse this date to get results from database, i tried to make it by many ways, but I can't find any fine. As i read it should work.

```
//2016-01-04
SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss:SSS");
Timestamp filterDateFromTs = new Timestamp ((dateFormat.parse(filterDateFrom)).getTime());
```

But I get

> java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "2016-01-04".

Comment: Your date format expects a time component and there is none in "2016-01-04".  Remove the hh:mm:ss:SSS or add the time component in that format to the date being passed.

Comment: Oh, now i get it. Its not about telling what should be but what it get. Thank you.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You are trying to parse `2016-01-04` hence you should be using `yyyy-MM-dd` and not `yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss:SSS`.

Try this instead:

```
SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
Timestamp filterDateFromTs = new Timestamp ((dateFormat.parse(filterDateFrom)).getTime());
```